# How to check for duplicate usernames and notify users with AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, activerecord

I'm currently trying to get my username validation method to work with case sensitivity. The normal method sees the username characters as unique by default, and I need it to see "John" == "john". How can I get my activerecord query method to validate the results no matter how the word itself is written? The code that I have is below. Lastly, how can I format my AJAX request to alert the user that their username is available or unavailable? My code as it is, will fire off the error block without cause or an exception.

Console Error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (username = NUL...
                        ^
: SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (username = NULL)):

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:30:in `check_duplicate_username'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:33:in `activate_account_time_zone'
```

new.html.erb

```
 $( "#user_username" ).blur(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%= check_duplicate_username_path %>',
                type: "GET",
                data: { username: $('#username').val() },
                complete: function() {},
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

                    alert("Your username is available!");
                    if (data.available == false)
                    {
                        $('#username').addClass("error");
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Something went wrong on our end!")
                }
            });
        });
```

users_controller.rb

```
def check_duplicate_username
    #@user = User.where('username = ?', params[:username]).first
    @user = User.where('username = ?', params[:username]).distinct
    if @user.present?
      render json: {:success => 0, :message => 'Username taken', :user_available => true}
    else
      render json: {:success => 1, :message => 'Username available', :user_available => false}
    end
  end
```

routes.rb

```
get '/check_duplicate_username' => 'users#check_duplicate_username', as: :check_duplicate_username
```

Comment: what is your DB collation? (Collations are the set of rules the DB is comapring values).

Comment: I'm using Postgres & Puma right now. The db collation is not set in database.yml.

Comment: Could you do: `User.where('upper(username) = ?', params[:username].upcase)`?

Comment: db must have a collation. Can't do comparisons without. Find out what it is.

Comment: I tried Keith Bennett's approach, but I am getting a NoMethod error for upcase. My approach as is, won't fire off the javascript after it checks the username. I see the username being compared in the console, but nothing is happening in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Are you normalizing `username` before it goes into the database?

If not, then I'd suggest doing so in an ActiveRecord callback. Something like:

```
class User
  # ...
  before_save -> { self.username = self.username.downcase }
  # ...
end
```

Then the query in your controller helper (or class method on `User` ...) can be reduced to something like:

```
User.find_by(username: params[:username])
```

Also, 1) if you already have data in your database, you should create a migration which does that for all historical data and 2) add a uniqueness constraint and/or ActiveRecord validation to prevent duplicate usernames.

Comment: My JS code is not firing off when I compare the username input to the username in the database. Can you check my code above to see what is wrong?